# undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DebugString[abi:cxx11]() const

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers, caffe

I am trying to build DeepLabv2's version of caffe.
I am using anaconda2 for package management.

I get the following errors:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.10, needed by /home/asim/anaconda2/lib/libmatio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DebugString[abi:cxx11]() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&))'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName[abi:cxx11]() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned char*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::fixed_address_empty_string[abi:cxx11]'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString[abi:cxx11]() const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::NameOfEnum[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const*, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::internal::MigrationSchema const*, google::protobuf::Message const* const*, unsigned int const*, google::protobuf::MessageFactory*, google::protobuf::Metadata*, google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const**, google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor const**)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/home/asim/anaconda2/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Rdereference'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeToString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:621: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1
```

I tried to add Library Directories to the Makefile.

Specifically

```
LIBRARY_DIRS += /home/asim/anaconda2/lib /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Have you added the protobuf library to the makefile

Comment: @P.W. I have passed the path of anaconda library to the linker using 
"-Wl,-rpath-link,/path to anaconda/lib". There protobuf libraries are also present. 
Also, I removed the warning of libhdf5.so.10 not being present by creating a softlink using an existing libhdf5.so.101 file. But the errors persist

Comment: I usually encounter these types of errors when the build is unable to find the protobuf libraries. Using CMake, it is possible to check if the libraries are really included or not. I don't know if this is possible to do using make.